# I have Created reusable-delegation-set and wish to associate it with a HostedZone through CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, devops

I wish to associate an existing reusable delegation set with a Hosted Zone I wish to create using CloudFormation but unable to see any examples/documentation on the subject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating delegation sets or assigning delegation sets to a hosted zone is not supported using `CloudFormation`.

See this:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/route-53-concepts.html#route-53-concepts-reusable-delegation-set

> **reusable delegation set** A set of four authoritative name servers that you can use with more than one hosted zone. By default, Route 53
>   assigns a random selection of name servers to each new hosted zone. To
>   make it easier to migrate DNS service to Route 53 for a large number
>   of domains, you can create a reusable delegation set and then
>   associate the reusable delegation set with new hosted zones. (You
>   can't change the name servers that are associated with an existing
>   hosted zone.)
>
> **You create a reusable delegation set and associate it with a hosted
>   zone programmatically**; using the Route 53 console isn't supported. For
>   more information, see CreateHostedZone and CreateReusableDelegationSet
>   in the Amazon Route 53 API Reference. The same feature is also
>   available in the AWS SDKs, the AWS Command Line Interface, and AWS
>   Tools for Windows PowerShell.

Comment: While I believe you are correct about CloudFormation not supporting this fearure, I don't see where the documentation you have cited actually states this.  References to the console, here, are referring to the Route 53 console.

Comment: Not saying it is supported generally means it is not supported.